# Proof of Denseness

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**Theorem.** The set of elements of the form $\frac{m}{2^n}$ where $m \in [0, 2^n]$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is dense in the set $[0,1]$.

---

**My Proof.** Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ where $a < b$. Since $a < b$, $b - a> 0$. Using the Archimedean property, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$ 
n(b-a) > 1,
$$
hence 
$$
b-a > \frac{1}{n} > 0.
$$
Since $2^n > n$ for any $n$ (easily shown by induction), $\frac{1}{2^n} < \frac{1}{n}$. Hence, 
$$
b - a > \frac{1}{n} > \frac{1}{2^n} > 0.
$$
Hence, 
$$
\frac{1}{2^n} < b - a,
$$
hence, 
$$
1 < 2^n (b - a) = b2^n - a 2^n. 
$$
The distance betweenn $b2^n$ and $a2^n$ is larger than $1$, so there's some integer between them. Call it $z$. Since $a < b$, $a2^n < b2^n$. Hence, 
$$
a2^n < z < b2^n.
$$
$2^n \neq 0$ for any $n$. Hence, 
$$
a < \frac{z}{2^n} < b.
$$

Hence, proved.

---

Is there anything wrong with this proof? I proved it for an interval $(a,b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are assumed to lie in $(0,1)$, though I don't think there is anything special about $[0,1]$. This same fact could be established for $\mathbb{R}$. I also don't think I used the fact that $m \in [0, 2^n]$, but if $b < 1$, then $b2^n < 2^n$ and it's certainly greater than $0$, so it seems that this also holds.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is fine. You proved that $a<b$ implies there exist an integer $m$ and  a positive integer $n$ such that $\frac m {2^{n}}$ lies between $a$ and $b$. In case $(a,b) \subseteq [0,1]$ you automatically get $0\leq m \leq 2^{n}$ since $0 \leq a < \frac m {2^{n}} <b \leq 1$.